# Custom chain filter in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

everybody!

I've got a problem: I can't write filter in Angular used in a filter chain. I'm not familiar with Angular enough so I hope this is gonna be a a trivial mistake in my code.

So, first of all my js file with filters (I presume I could do something completely stupid so I provide it in almost form):

```
(function () {
    angular.module('myModule')
        .filter('firstFilter', function () {
            return function (input) {
                    return input;
                }
        });

    angular.module('myModule')
        .filter('secondFilter', function () {
            return function (input, firstParam, secondParam) {
                return input;
            }
        });
})();
```

Then goes a piece of my html that makes using of the secondFilter:

```
<tr ng-repeat="someObject in (someObjects | secondFilter : firstParam : secondParam)"></tr>
```

But when the page is loaded it gives me the error:

```
Unknown provider: secondFilterFilterProvider
```

I could write the full error message if needed. Waiting for any help, thanks!

Comment: You have a syntax error. There's an extra `}` in the first filter.

Comment: @Amir I'm terribly sorry, this was a mistake when I cut away all the logic. Now there's no extra }, but I the same error.

Comment: I dont see any problems here. https://plnkr.co/edit/1rRBO5pN5rOvnuPNvjCK?p=preview maybe i changed something .. idk

Comment: @Amir Thank you for you demo, I will use this one as an example in future! Then I guess there is an error related to the whole ng-repeat. Here it is: ng-repeat="object in (filteredObjects = (objects | filter : {category: objectCategoryFilter.name} | filter : fullTextSearch)) | secondFilter : begin : limit" Angular parsing fails exactly here on this line

Comment: Why do you have a `=` inside `ng-repeat` (`filteredObjects = ...`)? not sure if it is related though.

Comment: @Amir For the sake of simplicity I suppose. This code was written before me. And it worked just fine. The only change here: my filter

Answer (score 0):

It's because the function return by a filter take only the input in parameter to pass other parameter you can do something like :

```
 angular.module('myModule')
        .filter('secondFilter', function (firstParam, secondParam) {
            return function (input) {
                return input;
            }
        });
```

and you can call it like this in your code :

```
<tr ng-repeat="someObject in someObjects | filter:secondFilter(firstParam, secondParam)"></tr>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's a great idea! Unfortunetely, it seems it doesn't work:c Maybe this point can be helpful: I use this filter instead of limitTo (I am to add some custom logic there). So previously these code used limitTo filter like this: limitTo: begin : limit

Comment: ok i understand now if you previously use limit To. what do you me an vu doesn t work ? the filter is not called or you have an error in the console? i also update my reply it miss a parenthesis in the end.

Comment: I have both the problems) Filter is not called as the error is thrown right off from the start when the page tries to load.